# What’s the Difference Between Grass and Sedge?

Tags: botany, homework, terminology, plant-anatomy, classification

What’s the difference between grasses and sedges? in terms of anatomy and classification.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short answer

Sedges have edges, and they're in different families.

See [Minnesota Wildflowers](https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/page/grasses-sedges-rushes) for a great summary with images.

### Long answer

Both are in the order [Poales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poales), but they are in different families:

- Grasses = [**Poaceae**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poaceae) (of the graminid clade)
- Sedges = [**Cyperaceae**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyperaceae) (of the [non-monophyletic]<sup>1</sup> cypirid lineage)

**Some anatomical differences**:

[image]

<sup>Compiled using info from [here](https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/page/grasses-sedges-rushes) and [here](https://www2.palomar.edu/users/warmstrong/termfl3.htm)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Source: [New York Botanical Garden](http://sweetgum.nybg.org/science/projects/fg/glossary-details/?irn=3085)</sup>

---

<sup>Citations</sup>

<sup>1. Bouchenak-Khelladi, Y., Muasya, A.M. and Linder, H.P., 2014. A revised evolutionary history of Poales: origins and diversification. *Botanical Journal of the Linnean Society*, 175(1):4-16.</sup>

Comment: What is an "edge" in this context?

Comment: @Terdon see the stem shape. Sedges have triangular stems instead of round. Each face of the triangle is an "edge"